# How does Node treat two o more users simultaneously?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io, pm2

I got several applications working with `Node` on the back-end and `React` on the front-end, it works great, I do `axios` get and post requests from `React` to `Express` and I get data back and forth, then on production I use `pm2` to get everything up and running.

My question is when two users access the same application at the same time, how does `Node` treat this, as two separated instances or just one?.

I am considering using `socket.io` to be able to notify the front-end on changes that are happening on Node, and I wonder if those notifications will be emitted from the back-end no matter what another user might be doing or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you have probably heard node.js is addressed as a "single-threaded" runtime. This is only partially true. Even though node runs on a single thread of your processor it runs the majority of its tasks in a thread pool which can process up to 4 tasks at the same time.
If you want to know about this you might want to look into the node event loop which describes the steps node goes through on each "tick".
So as you see node can often not process one but up to 4 actions on each loop cycle. But there is more, to solve the performance issues that might occur on big applications you can run node on a cluster mode. This allows you to extend the thread pool and add multiple node instances and therefore handle high demand efficiently.

One note to your socket.io question. As you see a high demand of tasks gets queued until it is handled in the node event loop, so sometimes you need to wait. Fortunatly we are in a race of big tech to create the fastest JS-runtime so this thing is pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so basically if I run `socket.io` on node and a user gets notification on the front end this will not conflict with another user using the same app at the same time?

Comment: I dont think so, events get scheduled in the event loop and will be processed one after another. If you are ever going to have so much users that you see performance problems look into cluster mode and you will be set for 99,8% of applications.
Please feel free to accept my answer if it solved your question.